# How to efficiently handle insertion or deletion in the middle of a big file?

Tags: filesystems, storage, bigdata

`Insert` and `Delete` are operations that add and remove some data in the middle of a file, with the size of the file changed.

For small text files edited by normal text editors, such as notepad, vim, emacs, the whole text file is rewritten by a atomic operation. Concretely, when a text file is edited with some content (not at the tail of the file) are inserted or removed, first, the content from the head of the file to where data are inserted or deleted is copied into a new file; then, the inserted data is copied (delete operation omits this step); at last, data from inserted/deleted position to the end is copied into the new file.

'Insert' and 'Delete' are expensive operations, because

> Normal file systems do not provide `insert` or `remove` operations that modify  the file content in the middle with file size changed.

When comes to a big file — which here refers to a file with a size over the size of the memory, normally over 10G Bytes — the cost is extremely high if the whole file is still rewritten. Thus, the software that owns big files normally handle the modifications to the file by themselves. Such as,

1. `vmdk` files are virtual machine image files arranged by a virtual file system of the VMware Workstation
2. `db` files are database files and their data are manipulated by the storage engine of the database

My question is **how these "virtual file system/storage engine" efficiently handle the `insert` and `delete` operations in the middle of a big file, to avoid intensive disk I/O?**

Any relative materials or papers are welcome.

Answer (score -1):

I would be interested to know whether any file system has specific optimization for insert/remove in between. AFAIK lot of file systems has no specific optimization all new data (from place of modification till end) is re-written again in sequential manner.

Comment: For compatibility, file systems only provides some basic operations for files, excluding `insert` or `remove` in the middle, file editors or the owner of the file have to make optimization for their own.